# Node.js download a file from a URL with a username and password?

Tags: node.js

From the CLI I can download an IBM Watson token and save it as the file `token`:

```
curl -X GET --user username:password --output token
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
```

How do I do this in Node? My best guess is:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var username = 'groucho';
var password = 'swordfish';

var header = { 
    // where does https go?
    Host: 'stream.watsonplatform.net',
    Path: '/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api',
    Authorization: username:password
  };

var download = function(header, dest, cb) {
  var file = fs.createWriteStream("/javascript/services/token");
  var request = http.get(header, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });
  }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
    fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
    if (cb) cb(err.message);
  });
```

Is it a problem issue is that the server is `https` when I have Node set for `http`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the `https` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this a lot easier you can use the [watson developer cloud package for speech to text](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk#speech-to-text) Here is an example on how easy it can be using the package. This example is straight from the docs

```
var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
var fs = require('fs');

var speech_to_text = new SpeechToTextV1({
  username: '<username>',
  password: '<password>'
});

var params = {
  // From file
  audio: fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav'),
  content_type: 'audio/l16; rate=44100'
};

speech_to_text.recognize(params, function(err, res) {
  if (err)
    console.log(err);
  else
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
});

// or streaming
fs.createReadStream('./resources/speech.wav')
  .pipe(speech_to_text.createRecognizeStream({ content_type: 'audio/l16; rate=44100' }))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./transcription.txt'));
```

Now if you really only care about getting the token and only the token using a request I would suggest using the [request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var request = require('request');
var username = 'username',
    password = 'password',
    url = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api';

request({url: url}, function (error, response, body) {
   // Do more stuff with 'body' here
});
```

Comment: 'request' looks great but I get the error message "Error: Cannot find module 'request'". I installed it with 'npm install request -g' and 'npm list --depth=0 -g' shows 'request@2.82.0'. I'm stumped...

Comment: IBM Watson Cloud SDK looks good too but I'm not sure how to call 'SpeechToTextV1' from AngularJS. I have a line 'var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({' Would I replace that with 'var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToTextV1.recognizeMicrophone({'?

Comment: You would call the watson cloud SDK from the backend. To my knowledge Angular is a front end framework.

Comment: for request try `npm install --save request` this will install it and add it to your dependencies in package.json. Then its important to restart your server.

Comment: I forgot about 'package.json'! And you left out the '@' in the URL: 'url = 'https://' + username + ':' + password + '@stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api';' Now it works, thanks!

Comment: I'm not going to use IBM Watson Cloud SDK from the back end, I'm running it from the front end.

Comment: ah okay, let me edit that `@` back in. Glad that worked for you!

Answer (score 2):

What about calling `curl` as a child process?

```
const
    URL = "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api",
    curlCommand = `curl -X GET --user username:password --output token ${URL}`,
    {
        exec
    } = require('child_process');

exec(curlCommand, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            // your callback
});
```

Comment: That was easy! Thanks!